# Change animation of fragment already in stack

Tags: java, android, animation, android-fragments

Assume I run the following code to place a fragment into the stack. It sets the animations for when I initially view the fragment and for when the fragment is exited.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left,
                                        R.anim.no_anim,
                                        R.anim.no_anim_show,
                                        R.anim.slide_right_away);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, tag);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

If i want to change the exit animation at a later time, how could I do this? As in,  if I had the following code:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

But I want a different animation then the one I originally placed into the stack.

Answer (score 2):

The following is what I tried, and it worked:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(
        R.anim.slide_left, R.anim.new_anim)
        .remove(fragment)
        .commit();
```

So, it looks like I had to explicitly 'remove' the fragment in a new fragment transaction, in order to make use of the new exit animation

Answer (score 1):

You can change the custom animation before popping from back stack

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left,
            R.anim.no_anim,
            R.anim.no_anim_show,
            R.anim.new_pop_exit).commit();
```

and execute pending transactions before popping back stack

```
getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
```

Note : popExit animations will be played for exit operations specifically when popping the back stack

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I'm wondering whether, since it's a new FragmentTransaction that we are adding the new animations to, the animations on the old one still stays and is still executed.